# Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentManager but FragmentActivity was expected

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

So I'm having an issue in Kotlin when migrating from viewpager to viewpager2.
Below is both the old working code, and the new attempt at migrating to viewpager2, as well as the error message I get when running the new code.

**Old working code**
DashboardFragment.kt

```
package com.example.profilside.ui.dashboard

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.example.profilside.R

class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)

        val viewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.view_pager2) as ViewPager
        // Important: Must use the child FragmentManager or you will see side effects.
        viewPager.adapter = MyAdapter(childFragmentManager)

        return root
    }

    class MyAdapter internal constructor(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

        override fun getCount(): Int = 2

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            if(position == 0){
                return ProfileStatsFragment.newInstance()
            }
            else {
                return ProfilePlatformsFragment.newInstance()
            }
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence = "Tab $position"
    }

    companion object {
        val TAG: String = DashboardFragment::class.java.name
    }

}
```

**New non-working code**
DashboardFragment.kt

```
package com.example.profilside.ui.dashboard

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.example.profilside.R

class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)

        val viewPager2 = root.findViewById(R.id.view_pager2) as ViewPager2
        // Important: Must use the child FragmentManager or you will see side effects.
        viewPager2.adapter = MyAdapter(childFragmentManager)

        return root
    }

    class MyAdapter internal constructor(fa: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {

        override fun getItemCount(): Int = 2

        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            if (position == 0) {
                return ProfileStatsFragment.newInstance()
            } else {
                return ProfilePlatformsFragment.newInstance()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val TAG: String = DashboardFragment::class.java.name
    }

}
```

When I try to run the last code I get the following error

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentManager but FragmentActivity was expected
```

**Edit:**
If anyone's curious, I followed [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#adapter-classes) to migrate from ViewPager to ViewPager2, and that is how I got the "New non-working code".

**Edit 2**
The error comes from this line
`viewPager2.adapter = MyAdapter(childFragmentManager)`, where childFragmentManager is the issue. Does anyone know if there is a replacement for childFragmentManager that can be used with FragmentActivity?

Comment: Replace `fa: FragmentActivity` with `fm: FragmentManager`

Comment: Now I get the following errors:

`None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: `

`public constructor FragmentStateAdapter(p0: Fragment) defined in androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter`

`public constructor FragmentStateAdapter(p0: FragmentActivity) defined in androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter`

Any other ideas?

Comment: Scratch that, I didn't edit like you said, here's the error I got when replacing `fa: FragmentActivity` with `fm: FragmentManader`. And without changing FragmentstateAdapter to fm.
Error: `Unresolved reference: fa`